# Angular ui.router does not replace view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The initial view, as well as the first State to be displayed properly, but when I click on the link of the first reloaded view the next State does not appear.
Below the [`codepen`](http://codepen.io/amlang/pen/OMQVvo/). The URL is modified but the new content will not be reloaded.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have set the second state to be a child of the first, but you don't have a view for it to render in. When you use a state-name such as `new.two` you are effectively saying: Render state "two" into the the child-view of state "new".

If that was the goal, then you need to add a ui-view into the template of the first state. If that wasn't the case, then change `new.two` to just `two`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have ui-view in your parent `state`.

```
    .state('new', {
      controller: "AsdCtrl",
      url: '/new',
      template: "<h1>TEST</h1><a ui-sref='new.two'>Lalalal</a><div ui-view></div>"
    })
```

This state should have `ui-view` like so in order to load the child html.

> Child states will load their templates into their parent's ui-view.

[Read more here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)

And here you go the working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWZbVW)

Comment: But then the new view is only displayed underneath. However I would like to replace the complete view by the new state

Comment: Then `two` should not be a child of `new`. You should name is just `two` instead of `new.two`.